# Areas of Europe with more women than men have higher GDP and lower unemployment. Why might this be?

Tags: gdp, unemployment, demographics, european-union

Using Eurostat data I've found that regions of Europe with more women than men (i.e. female biased sex ratio) have higher GDP and lower unemployment than areas with male biased sex ratios. any idea why this might be?
Cheers

Comment: Could you share a link to your datatable? In case this is not possible: could you control for population density, e.g., look only at areas with less than 10 people/km^2?

Comment: And when you say "regions", what granularity are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is generally true in the US, and I'll offer at a few reasons that are sometimes suggested here.

1. [Women are more likely to go to college than men](https://www.theatlantic.com/education/archive/2017/08/why-men-are-the-new-college-minority/536103/), and [colleges tend to be located in higher productivity areas](https://www.theatlantic.com/business/archive/2017/03/regional-productivity/521376/).
2. Women are more likely to live and work in cities ([a majority in 81 of the 100 largest cities but a majority in only 58 percent of small metropolitan areas](https://www.bestplaces.net/docs/studies/solocities.aspx) ), and [wages are higher in cities](https://www.usnews.com/news/articles/2016-12-08/in-americas-rural-urban-divide-age-earnings-and-education-are-prominent).
3. [Depending on the sample period, for much of the time since 2007 female unemployment rates have been lower than the male rate](https://www.macrotrends.net/2511/unemployment-rate-men-women), so you might expect places with more women to have have lower unemployment rates.

Comment: The first point however definitely is true in Europe as well https://www.unece.org/info/media/news/statistics/2019/women-outnumber-men-in-higher-education-but-gender-stereotyped-subject-choices-persist/doc.html

Comment: The last bit also not true on unemployment in general in Europe https://bit.ly/2vVqvjL